# xserver didn't show result from Xsensor

Tags: networking, wireless, sensors, tinyos, nesc

i have build the example Xsensor for 420cc then i plug it and put the sensor board on it, on other side for the serial board i build Xsniffer (TOSBase) to the mote that i need to put it on the 520MiP serial USB.

To see the message send form mote 1 to the mote 2, i try to open cygwin terminal and type `xserve -device=com4` then it open serial device but there is nothing display !!

i have try to change the (TOSBase) by (XMeshBase) to see if this will be useful,
but this mote with (XMeshBase) use it on serial USB, but still there is no output on xserve.

note: when i try to open MoteVeiw the output terminal it give me that it receive ""Heartbeat received""
but with no field or data !

i use Xmesh to send packet but i get this information, i didn't understand the meaning of these data ? i feel that they are the same !!

this what appeared ? [image: Xserver]